# Hibernate JPA Persistence multiple database with Spring

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to add a new connection to my project based on Spring, JPA and Hibernate. I dont know what's wrong with my settings when I add the second connection

database.properties

```
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.33.333.33:1530:sid
database.username=user
database.password=pass

#DB2
database2.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
database2.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.33.333.33:1530:sid
database2.username=user2
database2.password=pass
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitUno" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>                
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="user"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitDos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>           
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="user2"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <context:spring-configured/>

    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:config/ehcache.xml"/>
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="com.project.cache.CacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
    </bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com.project.interceptor.component.*" />
    </context:component-scan>


    <cache:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSourceUno">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
    </bean>    


    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSourceDos">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database2.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database2.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database2.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database2.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactoryUno">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitUno"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceUno"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactoryDos">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitDos"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceDos"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManagerUno">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryUno"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManagerDos">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryDos"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" >
        <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactoryUno"/>
    </bean> 

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

Error:

```
 INFO ||  || Class: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean || Line: 285 || Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'persistenceUnitUno'
 INFO ||  || Class: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean || Line: 285 || Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'persistenceUnitDos'
 INFO || Date:  || Class: java.sql.DatabaseMetaData || Line: 147 || HHH000262: Table not found: TABLE

.....

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: TABLE
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1335)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 22 more
```

the TABLE on the error belongs to the first user scheme, it should not happen in user2.

Comment: Try adding <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> in both your persistence units.

Comment: OK, im trying again and the result is a new error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TableParameter is not mapped. Really strange error, this table belongs to first persistence unit

Comment: Well, as you have not listed any classes in persistence.xml what would you imagine <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> might do? Exclude everything maybe? This answer I have posted below will work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Entities reside in different packages, you can control which entities are associated with each persitence unit by setting the `packagesToScan` property as below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactoryUno">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitUno"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceUno"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.test.domain.entitiesforpu1.package1</value
            <value>com.test.domain.entitiesforpu1.package2</value
        </list>
    <property> 
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactoryDos">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitDos"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceDos"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.test.domain.entitiesforpu2.package1</value
        </list>
    <property> 
</bean
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan-java.lang.String...-

If the entities are not in separate packages then the other option is to explicity list the classes in each persistence unit and exclude any lised which would look like:

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitDos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>           
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="user2"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>

     <class>com.acme.Entity1ForPu2</class>
     <class>com.acme.Entity2ForPu2</class>
     <class>com.acme.Entity3ForPu2</class>
     <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: In our project, we dont have a package with the tables belong to dataSourceDos. dataSourceDos until now is a js component that work correctly cause both schemes are in the same direction. is neccesary be mapped now?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your comment but have updated the answer.

Comment: sorry, meant that the second connection does not have classes in any package within the project, it is a call to a database that is in the same scheme. a request is made by HQL

Comment: Well use one of mu solutions. Either set packagesToScan empty in PU2 or use <exclude-unlisted-classes/> in PU2.